# Are there formulas in Excel to create charts without using the ChartWizard?

Tags: php, excel, charts, xls

I'm using a neat JQuery plugin called JQuery.sheet to do some simple web spreadsheets with charts. It has some chart formulas like "=BARCHART(A1:A10)", for example, to render a chart. Does Microsoft Excel have something similar? It would be nice for exporting spreadsheets with charts from PHP, without having to use external libraries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via VB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213352

This'd mean using something PHPExcel to embed VB in a spreadsheet you're creating. Embedding languages in languages to accomplish something is always such fun...